# BBEG Ideas for my campaign?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, multi-classing, campaign-development, villain

So I'm planning on starting my own campaign for the first time. I have the story planned out and what the BBEG's motives will be. However I want to have him be a combination of classes, and I was wanting to know other's opinions.

> wakfu So the BBEG is essentially an accidental Lich (To those who have seen Wakfu, this idea is loosely themed on Nox the Watchmaker). He stumbled upon a purple cube that was originally meant to be a gift to the dragons from the gods. However, a demon caught hold of it and cursed it with insanity. The BBEG, without knowing of the cubes purpose or its curse, took it for himself and began trying to figure out what it is. After spending years trying to figure it out, he realized his family (a wife and daughter) had died years ago. Stricken with grief he blamed the cube and left it, trying to find someone who could send him back in time. The cube began telling him that it could help him. With the years of grief and insanity, he listened to it. Once he set to work, the gods, fearing what could happen, left the world, taking the moon and stars with them. Now, 15,000 years later he's almost finished his plan, to drain the life energy from every living thing he can in order to go back in time.

> Okay, now I know that the story is essentially a ripoff of Wakfu, but I have several more unique ideas for smaller stories, and the BBEG is the only real reference of any sort. As for the BBEG, I thought a warlock: the hexblade, artificer: forge adept. I feel that this could work well for the character (since he's become a warforged of sorts in that time) but also as a slave to the cube. But I also wanted to maybe add a class based on his obsession with life and death of a sort. He's a more physical fighter with Magical support abilities. I have thought of letting him have a total leveling of 25-30, to allow for more diversity in his skillset.

**TLDR;** I have an immortal warforged lich BBEG who is trying to go back in time with a demon-cursed cube that drains life from what's around it. Thoughts on Class? Max level of 30.

I rolled his stats and haven't placed them yet, they are as follows. 14,14,15,16,17,17

Comment: [I've been told my question is better suited to a forum, but where should I go?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go)